# why to store https.get () inside a request const in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

In simple javascript, When we write to anything in the console then it is displayed on the console. Like as shown below.

```
const name = "david";
```

So it will display **david** on the console.

But in node.js, when I store the request in a const variable. It is not showing anything. Do I need to call that?

**Here is my problem**

```
    const https = require (https); 
    const request = https.get("https://somename.com/${username}.json", response = { 
       console.log(response.statusCode); 
    });
```

So when the above code will get called?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: *So it will display david on the console.* - it won't. The code you've posted is invalid. It's likely `response => {`. `https.get(...)` will be called immediately, and  `response =>` callback function will be called asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to defer the actual invocation of the HTTP GET request to a later point in your code. I suggest wrapping your GET request inside a function, like that:

```
const request = () => https.get("https://somename.com/${username}.json", response => { console.log(response.statusCode); });
```

Then you can invoke `request` like that when you want to trigger the HTTP GET request:

```
request();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

You will get your data inside the callback and under `res.on`.

```
const https = require('https');

https.get('https://somename.com/${username}.json', (res) => {
  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('headers:', res.headers);

  res.on('data', (d) => {
    console.log(d); //here you will get data
  });

}).on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});
```